# How does WebStorm detect whether it should use mocha or karma as test runner?

Tags: mocha.js, karma-runner, webstorm

I'm developing a Vue.js project in WebStorm 2017.2.3.

I have two unittest files under ./test/unit/specs.

When I right-click the first file I have the option of creating a Karma run configuration. For the second file I have the option of creating a Mocha run configuration, which doesn't work as we use Karma for testing.

**How does WebStorm detect whether it should use mocha or karma as test runner?** This is really confusing.

More observations to support the answer:

- In the parent folder a karma.conf.js file can be found.
- When I rename or copy the second file it seems to be fixed. Now WebStorm recognizes that it should be tested with Karma.
- There is a third test file in the same folder and if I right-click I have an option named "Create " with a JS-icon.
- In one case I find that renaming the file from s2.data.spec.js to ProductCatalog.spec.js changes the behavior of WebStorm. In the first case it suggests to use Mocha, in the second Karma.